# SQL - Get the sum of several groups of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, sql-max

**DESIRED RESULT**

Get the hours SUM of all [**Hours**] including only a single result from each [**DevelopmentID**] where [**Revision**] is highest value

*e.g SUM 1, 2, 3, 5, 6* (Result should be 22.00)

[image: SQL MAX]

I'm stuck trying to get the appropriate grouping.

```
DECLARE @CompanyID INT = 1

SELECT  
  SUM([s].[Hours]) AS [Hours]
FROM
  [dbo].[tblDev] [d] WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN
  [dbo].[tblSpec] [s] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [d].[DevID] = [s].[DevID]
WHERE   
  [s].[Revision] = (
    SELECT MAX([s2].[Revision]) FROM [tblSpec] [s2]
  )
GROUP BY
  [s].[Hours]
```

Comment: `SUM([s].[Hours])` clashes with `GROUP BY [s].[Hours]`. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Stop splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `row_number()` to identify the latest revision

```
SELECT SUM([Hours])
FROM   (
           SELECT *, R = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DevID
                                                ORDER BY s.Revision)
           FROM   [dbo].[tblDev] d
           JOIN   [dbo].[tblSpec] s 
             ON   d.[DevID] = s.[DevID]
       ) d
WHERE  R = 1
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks for helping without the free insults.

Answer (score -1):

If you want one row per `DevId`, then that should be in the `GROUP BY` (and presumably in the `SELECT` as well):

```
SELECT s.DevId, SUM(s.Hours) as hours
FROM [dbo].[tblDev] d JOIN
     [dbo].[tblSpec] s
     ON [d].[DevID] = [s].[DevID]
WHERE s.Revision = (SELECT MAX(s2.Revision) FROM tblSpec s2)
GROUP BY s.DevId;
```

Also, don't use `WITH NOLOCK` unless you really know what you are doing -- and I'm guessing you do not.  It is basically a license that says:  "You can get me data even if it is not 100% accurate."

I would also dispense with all the square braces.  They just make the query harder to write and to read.